# python: connecting to an Oracle database using Oracle's wallet/tnsnames

Tags: python, database, oracle, database-connection, cx-oracle

So I can connect to an Oracle database as such:

```
import cx_Oracle as ora
dsnStr = ora.makedsn(host="ABC.COM", port="ABC_PORT", sid="ABC")
con = ora.connect(user="ABC_USER", password="ABC_PASSWORD", dsn=dsnStr)
print(con.version)
con.close()
```

and this works very well, but I would like to connect using the `Oracle wallet`/`tnsnames`/`database.properties` (I'm coming from the Java world). Couldn't find anything so far on how to achieve that. Also, how can I "configure" `cx_Oracle` in terms of the paths to these `Oracle wallet`/`tnsnames`/`database.properties` respective files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cx_Oracle uses the same techniques to connect to the database as SQL*Plus. So you can test with SQL*Plus first if you find that easier to do.

In order to do this you will need to create a sqlnet.ora configuration file. This allows you to set such parameters as the location of the [wallet file](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF257). The environment variable TNS_ADMIN can be used to specify the location of this and other configuration files (like tnsnames.ora) if it isn't found in the default location. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006) for more information.

Comment: I have checked that I can connect from my local machine using `sqlplus`. Unfortunately, `cx_Oracle` has problems reporting invalid username/password, as if he couldn't see/read the wallet. Any ideas?

Comment: What connect string are you using for sqlplus? And what connect string for cx_Oracle? I presume you are doing it on the same machine with the same environment variables and so forth?

Comment: Since all this goes via `tnsnames.ora`, the connection string is the same for both `sqlplus` and `cx_Oracle` I believe. The problem was solved by restarting the machine on which I'm working (yay!). I can then connect directly in python by simply `cx_Oracle.connect("/@THE_USER_NAME_FROM_TNSNAMES_ORA")`. Btw, the `cx_Oracle` documentation doesn't seem to touch on these things.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with converting the Java side to the C side needed by cx_Oracle but maybe the following will help show what cx_Oracle needs.  I'll use an example based on Oracle Exadata Express, which uses a wallet to connect, see the generic instructions for connecting scripting languages to Exadata Express [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/scripting-languages/cloud-3080568.html).

Your exact config & files may differ. As Anthony indicated, the security setup isn't specific to cx_Oracle.  More experienced & helpful security experts may lurk in other forums.

For Exadata Express, a pre-supplied wallet zip file is downloaded.  For Oracle Call Interface applications like cx_Oracle we just need these files from the zip: sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora, and cwallet.sso.  You will need to create/find these (or whater you need) files.

My files are:

**sqlnet.ora**:

```
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file)
                   (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="$TNS_ADMIN")))

SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes
```

**tnsnames.ora**:

```
dbaccess = (description=
          (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=whereever.com))
          (connect_data=(service_name=whereever2.com))   
          (security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=wherever2.com,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood Shores,ST=California,C=US"))  
       )
```

**cwallet.sso**:
I'll leave this to your imagination...

I put those three files in `/Users/cjones/Cloud` and set the environment to find them:

```
$ export TNS_ADMIN=/Users/cjones/Cloud
```

Now I can connect using the connection name in the `tnsnames.ora` file:

```
$ sqlplus -l cj/mypassword@dbaccess

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jul 6 10:20:21 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Jul 03 2018 13:00:06 +10:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

In cx_Oracle your `dsn` would be `dbaccess` too.