# How to hide password in Database Connection?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am writing a program to read an Oracle database from Python.

The big problem I have is that I want to hide the password. If necessary, I want the password to be entered even by means of a text field.

Here is the line of code I know to connect to an Oracle database with Python.

```
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'myUserName', password='myPassword', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Comment: Where do you want the password to be hidden? In the logs? What's stopping you from taking the password as input?

Comment: You can store the credentials in an Oracle Wallet.  See here - https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/260

Comment: I'm confused.  Your subject line mentions Database LInk, and all respondents have addressed an Oracle Database Link, but the body of your message says nothing about Oracle Database Link, and instead talks about some Python construct.

Comment: A "database link" is a special term for a connection between two databases. You're trying to connect from Python to an Oracle database; Python is not a database, so this is just called a "database connection". See similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186723/python-connecting-to-an-oracle-database-using-oracles-wallet-tnsnames

Comment: @EdStevens - OldProgrammer's response is about the OP's actual question - the answer is still "use a wallet"

Comment: @kfinity - I never suggested otherwise.  I was just trying to get the OP to clarify - for us, or for his own thinking - the discrepancy between his subject line and his actual content.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Better solution, don't provide a password at all in the definition of the DB LINK, then there's nothing to hide.

How to do this? Use a Wallet.

@connor-mcdonald shows how to do this here. 
 https://connor-mcdonald.com/2015/09/21/connection-shortcuts-with-a-wallet/

If you read the wallet docs, they generally talk about clients. In this case, you setup the wallet on the server, and the database 'is' the client, at least it is when opening a connection to a remote database via a DB_LINK, it'll get the required password from the wallet as defined in it's sqlnet.ora config.

Also (courtesy of @OldProgrammer) here's a relevant article from the [cx_oracle site on using Oracle Wallet](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/260).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to read in a login info:

```
#
# This function gets the login information out of a credentials file
#
def get_login_info(file):
    # Create an array of the lines of the file
    line = open(file, "r").readlines()
    # Create a new list to be used to append the cleaned / trimmed lines
    new_line = []
    # Loop through the file
    for a in line:
        # Get rid of any new lines ("enter")
        a = a.replace("\n", "")
        # Add the cleaned data to the new_line list
        new_line.append(a)
    # Set the username to be the first object
    username = new_line[0]
    # Set the password to be the second object
    password = new_line[1]

    # Return them
    return username, password
```

Then, use that and pass it to your connection string:

```
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

So an example file might be 
:

```
JerryM
Mypassword2019
```

And it would store `JerryM` as `username` and `Mypassword2019` as `password`

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple python module `cred.py` In the module, save user and password

```
user='myUserName'
pass='myPassword'
```

Now, when you run your python:

`import cred`

```
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=cred.user, password=cred.pass, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

This way your password is saved in another file. Make sure to place `cred.py` in the same path where your original python file is present.